# Regex to replace all letter with ~ and ´ for letters without an accent

Tags: javascript

I am creating a field that will serve as a slug. I already made the regex the way I want it to be, but I still need to change all letters with ~ and ´ ( ã í e.g) for letters without an accent.

My regex:

```js
slug
.toLocaleLowerCase()
.replace(/[^a-z0-9]/g, '-')
.replace(/(^-+)|(-+$)/g, '')
```

Comment: [Remove Accents](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/990904/remove-accents-diacritics-in-a-string-in-javascript), Take a look this may answer your question

Comment: Thanks! I had searched for it but couldn't find it.